# purrr::partial() but keeping function signature

Tags: r

I quite like `purrr::partial()`, which allows us to easily create partial functions. However, the partial function loses its remaining arguments from its signature (replaced with `...`):

```r
f <- function(x, y) {
  print(x)
  print(y)
  return(invisible())
}

ff <- purrr::partial(f, y = 1)

ff(2)
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 1

ff
#> <partialised>
#> function (...) 
#> f(y = 1, ...)
```

So when developing and trying to remember the positions or names of the remaining arguments for the partial function, we're forced to check the original function instead. So I decided to create my own version which keeps the arguments:

```r
partialize <- function(.f, ...)
{
  dots <- c(...)
  dotsNames <- names(dots)
  symbols <- rlang::syms(dotsNames)

  new.f <- .f

  args <- rlang::fn_fmls(new.f)
  args[names(dots)] <- NULL
  rlang::fn_fmls(new.f) <- args

  rlang::fn_body(new.f) <- rlang::expr({
    !!!mapply(rlang::call2, symbols, dots, MoreArgs = list(.fn = "<-"))
    !!rlang::fn_body(new.f)
  })

  return(new.f)
}
```

This function performs basically like `purrr::partial`, but keeps argument names.

```r
f <- function(a, b, d) {
  print(paste(a, b, d))
}

x <- partialize(f, a = 1, d = 3)

x
#> function (b) 
#> {
#>     a <- 1
#>     d <- 3
#>     {
#>         print(paste(a, b, d))
#>     }
#> }

x(2)
#> [1] "1 2 3"
```

Note how inspecting `x` shows its remaining argument `b`.

This method is different from `purrr::partial` in that arguments are eagerly evaluated. It also doesn't have a [bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/656) found in how `purrr::partial` handles invisible returns (though I'm sure you all will find plenty of others!).

```r
z <- 1
purrrf <- purrr::partial(f, d = z)
myf <- partialize(f, d = z)

purrrf(1, 2)
#> [1] "1 2 1"
#> [1] "1 2 1"
myf(1, 2)
#> [1] "1 2 1"

z <- 2
purrrf(1, 2)
#> [1] "1 2 2"
#> [1] "1 2 2"
myf(1, 2)
#> [1] "1 2 1"  # kept z = 1

purrrf
#> <partialised>
#> function (...) 
#> f(d = z, ...)

myf
#> function (a, b) 
#> {
#>     d <- 1
#>     {
#>         print(paste(a, b, d))
#>     }
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000000000806f8d8>
```

A big drawback I've found with `partialize` is that it doesn't work with generic functions (i.e. those whose body is merely `UseMethod(...)`) with default values for their arguments. Since it sets the arguments as variables in its own environment instead of calling the original function with the arguments as actual arguments, the `UseMethod(...)` call doesn't catch the arguments.

```r
partialize(mean, na.rm = TRUE)
function (x, ...) 
{
    na.rm <- TRUE
    {
        UseMethod("mean")
    }
}
```

As always, happy for any and all comments on the code, and if anyone can figure out how to allow for lazy evaluation (so as to keep in line with `purrr::partial`), that'd be great.

---

To be clear: `partialize` is a function to be included in an in-house utility package, and is therefore somewhat generic. The function `f` above is merely a placeholder demonstrating `partialize`'s functionality, but the question here is essentially about how `partialize` itself has been written, whether it can be improved (by adding lazy evaluation or any other way you see fit) and if it has any drawbacks I haven't realized versus `purrr::partial`.